# Xcode comments just seemed to stop working. 8.2.1

Tags: xcode, xcode8

My comments short cut (command key + /) just has stopped working with 8.2.1, wondering if anyone else has this issue? Seems to have been an issue in the past.

Comment: This happens regularly to me. Just comment the line manually and then it will start working again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, a re-install of xcode fixed the issue.